# Making a list of cookies global

Tags: android, global, cookiestore

I want to use cookies stored in a list in a different activity which does a HTTPGET  request.(make it global or persist )

My code which stores the cookies is:

```
  HttpResponse sessionresp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  List<Cookie> cookielist=httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
   for (int i = 0; i < cookielist.size(); i++) {
                        Cookie cookie1 = cookielist.get(i);
                        Log.i("Cookie Store","Local cookie: " + cookie1);
                        //Cookie mSessionCookie = cookie1;
                        Log.i("Cookie Store",""+cookie1.getValue());
                        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie1);                 
                    httpclient2.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
```

}

I want to use these cookies in a different activity which does a HTTP GET operation. Any input ?

Comment: You can use singleton. In this case it wont be bad pattern, I think.

Comment: I am using an activity class actually but not sure how to use that for a list.

Comment: Just create new singleton class (for example CookieStore).

Comment: Yes, I have used the cookiestore in my code, please have a look.

Comment: It must be a singleton! Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). The thing is that when you create Class and only one object of this class can exist. And you can get this object from anywhere just calling `CookieStore.getInstance()` (thats how i called this class)

It would be smth like this :

```
class CookieStore {

         private CookieStore(){}

         private static CookieStore instance;

         private List<Cookie> cookies;

         public static CookieStore getInstance() {
              if (instance == null) {
                   instance = new CookieStore();
              }
              return instance;
         }

         public List<Cookie> getCookies()...

         public void setCookies(final List<Cookie> cookies)...

}
```

Comment: You made small mistake:
instead "public static getInstance() {..."
use "public static CookieStore getInstance() {..."